# Nginx cause chrome's 'ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH' and wget's 'Error decoding the received TLS packet.'

Tags: nginx

I use nginx(version 1.18.0) as my website server. Configuration of nginx uses 'default'. I have an static js file(about 3M).

- When i use chrome to load it, chrome gives me  (sometimes, not 100%).

```
ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH
```

- When use 'wget' to download it, it gives me (sometimes, not 100%)

```
Read error at byte 81569/2983955 (Error decoding the received TLS packet.). Retrying.
```

I want to know where problem is.

**update**

I did an experiment. If i use 'gunicorn' as server directly,  it does not have such a problem.Once nginx is used, it will appear.

**update**

In nginx's error.log, no any error information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution didn't work for me.

Adding the following directive to Nginx configuration solved my problem:

```
proxy_buffering off;
```

Answer (score 0):

guys. I resolve it by add below configuration to nginx.

```
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;   
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE:ECDH:AES:HIGH:!NULL:!aNULL:!MD5:!ADH:!RC4;  
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;   
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
```

Although resolved it, but i don't konw why!